# Bootstrap content doesn't lay out correctly in conjunction with fixed width sidebars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

There is a large white gap between the first row of columns and the second row.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5o3ug26g/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .content {
            margin-left: 170px;
            margin-right: 170px;
        }

        .sidebar { width: 160px; height: 600px; }
        .left { float: left; background: forestgreen; }
        .right { float: right; background: steelblue; }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div>
        <div class="left sidebar"></div>

        <div class="right sidebar"></div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">Text on top of the page</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">Other text on top of the page</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">I want this to be right below the "Text on top of the page" but it isn't...</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">... and I want this to be right below the "Other text on top of the page" but it isn't</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the `row` classes then the gap disappears, but this problem appears also when using Bootstrap `navbar`-s and other containers with `:after { display: table; }`, so just removing the `row` classes is not a solution.

I tried adding `clearfix` in a bunch of places but to no avail.

This is an extract from a more complex responsive layout and I'd rather avoid refactoring it all.

What is the easiest fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position your left and right sidebars absolutely instead of floating them. The floats are interfering with the bootstrap layout.

```
.left { background: forestgreen; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
.right { background: steelblue; position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}
```

Live example forked from yours: https://jsfiddle.net/5fk5900s/1/

Comment: Thanks. What if I had a variable height navigation bar on top though?

Comment: @Warplanes.Today You can wrap the sidebars and content in a div and set its position to relative. Just make sure the nav bar is outside this div.

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo is correct. You've already added margins to the content to account for the side bars. Here is a fiddle with the absolute positioning changes:

https://jsfiddle.net/5o3ug26g/1/

```
.content {
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-right: 170px;
}

.sidebar { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px; 
    height: 600px; 
}
.left { 
    left: 0px; 
    background: 
    forestgreen; 
}
.right { 
    right: 0px; 
    background: steelblue; 
}
```

Comment: Marcelo's edit beat me to showing the css implementation.